# Не срабатывает checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Не срабатывает `checkbox`, на котором висит `v-model`:

```js
  var app = new Vue({
    el : "#app",
    data : {
      products : [
        {
          name  : "Product #1",
          desc  : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia corrupti tempore ex ab aliquid ipsum voluptatem, veniam dicta, sit fugiat cum ipsa esse laborum sapiente temporibus sunt expedita inventore eligendi?",
          price : 89.00,
          check : true,
          list  : [
            {
              from : 1,
              to : 200,
              amount : 0.00
            },
            {
              from : 201,
              to : 1000,
              amount : 0.18
            },
            {
              from : 1001,
              to : 2500,
              amount : 0.14
            },
            {
              from : 2501,
              to : 5000,
              amount : 0.13
            },
            {
              from : 5001,
              to : 7500,
              amount : 0.11
            },
            {
              from : 7501,
              to : 10000,
              amount : 0.10
            },
            {
              from : 10001,
              to : 20000,
              amount : 0.09
            },
            {
              from : 20001,
              to : 1000000,
              amount : 0.08
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          name  : "Product #2",
          desc  : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia corrupti tempore ex ab aliquid ipsum voluptatem, veniam dicta, sit fugiat cum ipsa esse laborum sapiente temporibus sunt expedita inventore eligendi?",
          price : 80.00,
          check : false,
          list  : [
            {
              from : 1,
              to : 200,
              amount : 0.00
            },
            {
              from : 201,
              to : 1000,
              amount : 0.00
            },
            {
              from : 1001,
              to : 2500,
              amount : 0.00
            },
            {
              from : 2501,
              to : 7500,
              amount : 0.00
            },
            {
              from : 7501,
              to : 1000000,
              amount : 0.00
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name  : "Product #3",
          desc  : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia corrupti tempore ex ab aliquid ipsum voluptatem, veniam dicta, sit fugiat cum ipsa esse laborum sapiente temporibus sunt expedita inventore eligendi?",
          price : 80.00,
          check : false,
          list  : [
            {
              from : 1,
              to : 200,
              amount : 0.00
            },
            {
              from : 201,
              to : 1000,
              amount : 0.00
            },
            {
              from : 1001,
              to : 2500,
              amount : 0.00
            },
            {
              from : 2501,
              to : 7500,
              amount : 0.00
            },
            {
              from : 7501,
              to : 1000000,
              amount : 0.00
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name : "Product #4",
          desc : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia corrupti tempore ex ab aliquid ipsum voluptatem, veniam dicta, sit fugiat cum ipsa esse laborum sapiente temporibus sunt expedita inventore eligendi?",
          price : 0.00,
          check : false,
          list  : [
            {
              from : 0,
              to : 1000000,
              amount : 0.00
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name : "Product #5",
          desc : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia corrupti tempore ex ab aliquid ipsum voluptatem, veniam dicta, sit fugiat cum ipsa esse laborum sapiente temporibus sunt expedita inventore eligendi?",
          price : 0.00,
          check : false,
          list  : [
            {
              from : 0,
              to : 1000000,
              amount : 0.00
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name : "Product #6",
          desc : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia corrupti tempore ex ab aliquid ipsum voluptatem, veniam dicta, sit fugiat cum ipsa esse laborum sapiente temporibus sunt expedita inventore eligendi?",
          price : 0.00,
          check : false,
          list  : [
            {
              from : 0,
              to : 1000000,
              amount : 0.00
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      range : 100,
      total : 0
    },
    methods : {
      calculate : function(){
         this.total = 0;
        for(var i in this.products)
        {
          if (this.products[i].check)
            {
              this.total += this.count(this.products[i].price, this.products[i].list);
            }
        }
      },
      count : function(price, list)
      {
        for(var i in list)
        {
         if (list[i].from >= this.range && this.range <= list[i].to)
          {
            return price * (list[i].amount + 1);
          }
        }
      }
    },
    mounted : function(){
      this.calculate();
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
         {{ range }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-2">
          <span>
            <b>Invitations/manth:</b>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
          <input type="range" v-model="range" @input="calculate()" @change="calculate()" min="100" max="10000" step="100" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" v-for="(p, index) in products">
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label :for="'product-' + index">
                  <input :id="'product-' + index" @change="calculate()" v-model="products[index].check" type="checkbox" :disabled=" ! index" />
                  {{ p.name }}
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
            </div>
            <div class="media-right">
                <b>
                  {{ p.price }} $ / manth
                </b>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ p.desc }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
          <span>
            <b>
              Total: {{ total }} $ / manth
            </b>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/cuqajeseju/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1):

Замените click на change:

```
<input @change="calculate" v-model="products[index].check" type="checkbox" :disabled=" ! index" />
```